# Creating a postgresql stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

SQL1

```
SELECT pp.id, 
       TO_CHAR(pp.created_dt::date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS "Date", 
       CAST(pp.created_dt AS time(0)) AS "Time", 
       au.username AS "Initiator", 
       ss.name AS "Service", 
       pp.amount AS "Amount", 
       REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success') AS "Status", 
       pp.account AS "Props", 
       pp.external_id AS "Identifier", 
       COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'Indefined')  AS "External status"
  FROM payments AS pp
 INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id
 INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id
 WHERE pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date
        
  AND ss.name = 'SomeName' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'
```

This query returns specific data for each yesterday from database # 1

SQL2

```
SELECT pp.created_dt, pp.amount, pp.status_id, pp.service_id, pp.agent_id, pp.external_id
  FROM payment AS pp
 WHERE pp.service_id = 1
   AND pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date
   AND pp.status_id = 'SUCCESS'
```

This query returns specific data for each yesterday from database # 2

1. How can I make a stored procedure out of these requests?
2. These two queries (possibly through a procedure) should be compared with each other (only by the number of lines in them).
3. If these two queries are equal, the data of the first query (from database # 1) + 'true' should be displayed. In the event that they are not equal in the number of rows - I want to get 'false' + also get the query data (database # 1).

I need this to send reports. If, when comparing two requests with each other, I get 'true' - this report will be sent, otherwise the report will not be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create stored procedures in various languages. For plpgsql see the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql.html).
Basically for your SQL1 code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql1 
( IN Name varying character
, IN InStatus varying character
, OUT Date varying character
, OUT Time time
, OUT Initiator varying character
, OUT Service varying character
, OUT Amount varying character
, OUT Status varying character
, OUT Props varying character
, OUT Identifier varying character
, OUT External_status varying character
)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT ... ; -- copy here your SQL1 code
END ;
$$
```

Once you have created both stored procedures sql1 and sql2, you can compare the result with a join:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) OVER() = s2.ct THEN true ELSE false END, s1.*
FROM slq1(sql1_parameters) AS s1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) FROM slq2(sql2_parameters)) AS s2(ct)
```